# GoJS flowchart text on links

Tags: javascript, gojs

I'm trying to add text on links so I could create question-answer system. I find GoJS's flowchart most suitable for this task.

I'm trying to upgrade this example:
http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html

Example of text on links:
http://gojs.net/latest/samples/stateChart.html

Is there any way to add text on links in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for the problem.
In

```
    myDiagram.linkTemplate
```

code I just had to change panel atrribute:

```
    visible: true
```

Comment: By the way, **GraphObject.visible** defaults to true.

Answer (score 0):

This page covers the basic ideas: http://gojs.net/latest/intro/linkLabels.html.

You might want to look at the IVR Tree sample, http://gojs.net/latest/samples/IVRtree.html, which demonstrates another way of having labels on links.

Although the diagram structure is probably different from what you want, there's another style of showing link labels in the Concept Map sample, http://gojs.net/latest/samples/conceptMap.html and the State Chart sample, http://gojs.net/latest/samples/stateChart.html.